# Multisite: How can I have the admin bar (toolbar) use the language of the user instead of the language of the sub-site being viewed?

Tags: multisite, localization, language

By default in a network install, when viewing a sub-site, the **sub-site** language is used for the admin bar (toolbar).

How can I have the admin bar (toolbar) always use the language of the **user**?

Comment: Some quick experimenting shows me that the language of the Admin Bar changes when the user's Language setting (on their Profile page) is set to use a specific language (instead of the Site Default setting). At least, all the items added by Core seemed to change for me.

Comment: @PatJ are you sure? There is an unresolved ticket open describing the problem https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/38643

Comment: All I can say for sure is that, once I installed a 2nd language in my local WP installation, the Admin Bar seemed to respect the user's language settings. I didn't dig deep into it, and I don't have a lot of experience with translations — all the sites I deal with are English only.

Comment: @PatJ thanks. Is it possible your site locale and the user locale are both set to English? That may explain why the user's setting appears to be used. For example English

Comment: No, the 2nd language I installed was Canadian French, since I wanted something I could still read. When I switched the user's language (in the edit profile) screen to French, the Admin Bar core items were rendered in French, whether the site's language settings were French or English.

Comment: Cool. good to know. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Until there is a fix for it in Wordpress Core you can use this 'dirty' way:

**Switch to user locale before admin bar items are processed:**

```
add_filter( 'admin_bar_menu', 'ws390690_admin_bar_in_user_locale', 10, 1 );
function ws390690_admin_bar_in_user_locale($wp_admin_bar){
    switch_to_locale( get_user_locale() );
    return $wp_admin_bar;
}
```

**Switch back to site locale after admin bar has been rendered:**

```
add_filter( 'wp_after_admin_bar_render', 'ws390690_admin_bar_in_user_locale_back', 10, 2 );
function ws390690_admin_bar_in_user_locale_back(){
    restore_previous_locale();
}
```

As mentioned by @henrywright, its also in works here https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/38643

Comment: This helped, but I also had to remove the language from /wp-content/languages